Uploading Files using Flutter and Springboot
I'm having a problem with Futter and Springboot when uploading files. I'm getting an error "Internal Server Error: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported" when trying to send a request to Springboot Web API.
Flutter:
  @override
  Future<ResponseModel> save(
      OnlineReceiptRegister dto, List<http.MultipartFile> files) async {
    final url = '$baseUrl${'accounts_receivable/online_receipt_register'}';
    try {
      final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url))
        ..headers.addAll(await authHeader)
        ..fields['dto'] = json.encode(dto.toJson())
        ..files.addAll(files);

      final streamedResponse = await request.send();
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      return await ResponseUtil.getResponseModel(response);
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

Springboot:
@PostMapping("/online_receipt_register")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericReturnDto<?>> save(
            @RequestPart("dto") OnlineReceiptRegisterDto dto,
            @RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files,
            Errors errors) throws TransactionException{
        LOG.info("ONLINE_RECEIPT_REGISTER - POST-CREATE {}", dto);
        GenericReturnDto<OnlineReceiptRegisterDto> returnDto = new GenericReturnDto<>();
        try {
            if(!StringCustomUtils.isNULLOrEmptyString(StringCustomUtils.constraintHasError(errors))) {
                String exceptionMessage = StringCustomUtils.constraintHasError(errors);
                returnDto.setErrorCode(MainConstants.ERROR_CODE);
                returnDto.setMessage(exceptionMessage);
            }else {
                returnDto.setData(onlineReceiptRegisterService.save(dto,files));
                returnDto.setMessage(String.format(SUCCESS,returnDto.getData().getTransactionReference()));
            }
        }catch  (Exception e){
            returnDto.setErrorCode("0x01");
            returnDto.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(returnDto);
    }

